# Should I delete the development branch after merging it back into the master in gitflow?

Tags: git, git-flow

I have a feature branch `feature/doX`
And development branch `development` and master branch, `master`.
After finishing the implementation of the feature `doX`. I created a pull request from the feature branch into the development branch. My collegues reviewed the pull request, and did the merge.
After implementing many features, we did a pull request from the `development` branch into the `master` branch to prepare for our release build.
My question is: Should I delete the `development` branch after merging it back into the `master` branch and create new one for the next release features?

Comment: A branch is just a pointer to a commit. Delete it, keep it around, rename it - whatever.

Comment: Do you want to use `development` branch as a intermediate step when creating later releases?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to introduce feature implementation into the `master` branch before intensive testing took place

Comment: Comment on the `git-flow` tag: in GitFlow, `development` is branched into `release` that gets merged into `master`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no need to delete a branch that you still want to use after merging it (even if the merge is done with a pull request)